# Comparing a Stroke to a Path

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, vector-graphics, microsoft.ink

I want to analyze a user's input on an InkPresenter to a template.

Pseudo-xaml

```
<Canvas>
  <Canvas ScaleTransform="to match parent size">
    <Path Data="some line or bezier">
  <InkPresenter>
```

So, essentially, what I need is to determine the actual points, relative to the top level Canvas that the Path drew on the screen.  Also, I need to know directionality, i.e. did the start of the Stroke start near the start of the Path?

Perhaps it would be better to manually render the lines/curves instead of using the Path.Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm going with calculating the location of the Path to compare with StylusPoints on mouse down, move, and up.  Going pretty straight forward.  This code is very helpful - http://eztier.com/dba2day/?p=181